# Triangle with TextView and backgroud color

Tags: android-canvas

I want to make the triangle with `textView` inside that triangle in android studio, I know it can be drawn on the canvas but I am at a very beginner level.

Here is the first image of the triangle sample:

[image: first image fo the triangle sample]

and here is the second complete image:

[image: first image fo the triangle sample]

Comment: Actually, there is no need to use a textview. You could use the drawText()-method of canvas, couldn‘t you?

Comment: nah ... i dot know how to do that ...